# Verificar atributo data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vocês podem me dizer se é possível verificar se em uma imagem existe o atributo `data`? Isso somente com o selector img, não por ID ou class.

O que tenho:

```
<img data-src='http//.......'/>

if($('img').data('src)){
  alert();
}
```

Gostaria apenas de verificar se tal imagem tem atributo data ou não.

Exemplo:

```
<img data-src='http//.......'/>
```

ou não:

```
 <img src='http//.......'/>
```

Agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `.hasAttribute()` do JavaScript que já retorna um booleano se o atributo existe ou não no elemento:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].hasAttribute("data-src") // retorna true ou false
```

Ou outros métodos para verificar se é diferente de `undefined`. Nesses métodos, o código irá tentar pegar o valor do `data-src`. Se o atributo não existir, retornará `undefined`:

```js
// JS método 1
if( document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].hasAttribute("data-src") ){
   console.log("tem com JS puro - método 1");
}

// jQuery
if( $("img").data("src") !== undefined ){
   console.log("tem com jQuery");
}

// JS método 2 (IE11+)
if( document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].dataset.src !== undefined ){
   console.log("tem com JS puro - método 2");
}

// JS método 3
if( document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("data-src") !== undefined ){
   console.log("tem com JS puro - método 3");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-src />
```

> Mas isso só vai funcionar se você tiver apenas 1 `<img>` na página. Se tiver mais de uma, será necessário fazer um laço
>   para iterar cada um dos elementos, caso contrário só irá pegar o primeiro elemento `<img>`.

Comment: Muito obrigado agora deu certo!